# Activity to Fragment on button click

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-activity, navigationbar

I have navigation bar on my app. Using that has created fragments. I added regular activities to the app and I have found how to go from a Fragment page to an activity page with using the onclick method.

By the click of a button I want to go from an activity page to a fragment page. How do I go about that?

Thank you

Comment: If you want to come back to the same fragment, which started the activity then do finish() at the end and control will return back to invoking fragment. Hope it helps.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I used this for a "Cancel" button for it to go back to the previous Fragment. Is that the correct way to use it in that case?

Comment: If you want to move around in fragment then you have to be using either navigation bar clicks on tabs or use this from one fragment to another on a click of button .. see my answer .. i hope it fixes your problem .. if yes then pls mark it Answer. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

apply on click listner on the button and apply below code :-

```
Fragment fragment = new VehiclesFragment();
getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.container,fragment).commit();
```

Comment: Thanks, I have ano error for the fragment. Is this going to be the fragment that I want to go to? Do I leave out ".class" ?

Comment: Error:(79, 54) error: incompatible types: VehiclesFragment cannot be converted to Fragment

This was the code entered
VehiclesFragment vehiclesFragment = new VehiclesFragment();
                getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                        .replace(R.id.content_frame, vehiclesFragment).commit();

Comment: @arob please see my updated answer.and use the same code in your project.and replace this line VehiclesFragment vehiclesFragment = new VehiclesFragment(); to this  Fragment vehiclesFragment = new VehiclesFragment();

Comment: I did make that adjustment but it still didn't work. 
error: incompatible types: VehiclesFragment cannot be converted to Fragment

Comment: @arob Make sure that your VehiclesFragment classe extend Fragment class.

Comment: yes, the VehiclesFragment class extends Fragment. Any other suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to close the current activity to go back to your Fragment-container Activity you may call the finish() method or onBackPressed() method (in case you're not overriding it).

---

If you want to bring a fragment to the current activity you must have a fragment container and attach it with:

```
getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction.add(R.id.container, fragment, TAG).addToBackStack().commit();
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I used this but I got an error on "TAG". I am new to this :)

Comment: The tag is a String, whatever you want to identify your fragment

Comment: Ok I see. 

So would this code be in the onclick method?

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        switch (v.getId()) {
            case R.id.bSaveVehicle:
                  getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().add (R.id.container, fragment, TAG).addToBackStack().commit();}

Comment: Yes. And that will put your fragment in your container and will start its life cycle.

Comment: Getting an error on the fragment R.id.container,   "fragment" . Just to be sure, this is the name of the fragment I would like to go to afterms clicking a button correct?

Comment: The R.id.container is the name of your group view container (a FrameLayout maybe), fragment is your Fragment (Fragment fragment = new MyFragment();)

Comment: Oh ok. Got you, but I still get an error on the fragment. Is there something else I need to do?

Comment: error: incompatible types: VehiclesFragment cannot be converted to Fragment.replace(R.id.content_frame, vehiclesFragment).addToBackStack().commit();
Note: MainActivity.java uses or overrides a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
Note: Some messages have been simplified; recompile with -Xdiags:verbose to get full output
1 error

This was the code I used...
 VehiclesFragment vehiclesFragment = new VehiclesFragment();
getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
.replace(R.id.content_frame, vehiclesFragment).addToBackStack().commit();

Comment: Because you need a Fragment not a VehiclesFragment. Fragment vehiclesFragment = new VehiclesFragment();

Comment: Read Google's Fragments documentation and also OOP basics.

Comment: I changed it to Fragment but got the same error. 
Thanks, i will google it right now.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code..

```
 btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()){
 @Override
 public void onClick(View v) {
 Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(),FragmentTest.class);
 getActivity().startActivity(intent);

     }
 });
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. I am getting an error for getActivity. What do I need to do?

Comment: This is the error

Error:(77, 44) error: cannot find symbol method getActivity()

Answer (score 0):

If you want to move around in fragment then you have to be using either navigation bar clicks on tabs or use this from one fragment to another on a click of button .. like this

```
public void onNavigationDrawerItemSelected(int position) {
    FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();

Fragment fragment = Fragment.instantiate(MainActivity.this, <name of the fragment>);
            Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
            bundle.putBoolean(ALL_EVENTS, true);
            fragment.setArguments(bundle);
            fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.container, fragment).commit();
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the response, i am still getting errors with this.

Comment: When I put this code into the onNavigationDrawerItemSelected method, how do I call it by the click of a button in another activity to get to a fragment?

Answer (score 0):

Simply use this:

```
Intent(view.context, DestinationActivity::class.java).also {
    view.context.startActivity(it)

}
```